# what is equivalent of numpy.repeat() in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

```
a=['a','b','c']
s=[2,5,1]
a= numpy.repeat(a,s) 

a: ['a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c']
```

Is there something equivalent in JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

Not a straight forward equivalent but you can use [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to repeat the value according to the index in the second array :

```js
const a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const s = [2, 5, 1]

const result = a.flatMap((e, ndx) => Array.from({
  length: s[ndx]
}, () => e));

console.log({
  result
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatmap and fill the array.

```js
const
    repeat = (values, counts) => values.flatMap((v, i) => Array(counts[i]).fill(v)),
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    s = [2, 5, 1],
    result = repeat(a, s);

console.log(...result);
```